# How to host and connect to a remote WCF service that connects to a database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, web-services, wcf

I have written a WCF service that is responsible for accessing a MySQL database, and will eventually write a C# client application which consumes the service.

However I would like the clients to be able to access the service remotely. For this purpose what would be the ideal method of hosting/endpoint configuration and/or how would I access the service from a remote client.

I have looked through the following tutorials and a few other but still do not quite feel understand app domains, hosting, remote access concepts, nor do I have a clue how to remotely connect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx 
[Can a client remotely access WCF self-hosting Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191588/can-a-client-remotely-access-wcf-self-hosting-service)

Any good tutorials, sample code, suggestions or ideas or am I barking up completely the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the links, I am currently following the tutorial to set up IIS, I'll let you know how I get on as things progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have seen this done is to host the service on IIS, preferably IIS 7 Integrated.

Here is a link for hosting a WCF service on IIS.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hosting the service is actually relatively easy and takes just a few minutes.

You can then reference the hosted service, or even locally by hitting discover if it is not hosted yet, by adding a service reference to your C# project. If you have it hosted then add your URL defined in IIS 7. If you don't have it hosted just place the WCF service and the C# project under the same solution and hit discover.

Here is a link for adding a service reference to a project.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

You will want to setup an app.config file or a web.config file, depending on your type of application, so that you can define how your C# project will interact with your Service. What are my data request lengths, timeouts, buffer sizes, streamed or buffered transfer ect.

Sample:

```
<bindings>
    <binding name="MyBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
      openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
</bindings>
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:55010/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConfiguration"
        contract="IMyWcfInterface"/>
</client>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have installed IIS as shown but when I go to add an application to the default web site I get an "Invalid Application Path" error.

Comment: After negating various server errors caused by not installing properly and having a few things slightly mis-configured I now have  a service which seems to work (I can connect to it and get the correct page in browser). I will soon be setting up the client but that looks like the easier bit. Thanks for your guidance on this.

Comment: Is it possible to allow the user to change the address of the service which they wish to connect to at run-time without using SOAP, provided that they use the same code and asp.net version to run the service, just at a different address?

Comment: You might be able to if you figure out how to change the app.config/web.config file via code specifically the address property in the client tag. You might also have to find a way to make the service post it's metadata again. (Like a coded UpdateServiceReference). Those would be your two big obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

For hosting, I would recommend IIS with and http binding, the mechanism is similar with hosting a web application. Regarding accessing IIS hosted wcf service you just need to add a service reference to your client application (which will automatically generate a proxy class that can be used for accessing the service). You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)